# Where can you find the "planetarium" and the "mining laser"?

Tags: wheres-my-water-2

Where can you find the "planetarium" and the "mining laser" in where's my water? I have completed all the levels with 3 ducks and looking for the achievement wall completion

Answer (score 3):

1. *Planetarium* is on the achievement level screen, if you slide or scroll the screen down (farther to the top) you will see the icon.
2. *Ups and Downs* is on the collections screen, same trick as above.
3. *Mining laser* is on the Cranky free screen in the challanges.
4. *Sara's level* is on the Cranky free food groups.

Hope this helps anyone else that has the same frustrated incomplete achievement screen.